# How to make a shortcut to set title in gnome-terminal tab (ubuntu 13.10)?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I remember that in gnome-terminal there used be an option to set shortcuts in Edit menu. I've upgraded to ubuntu 13.10 and installed gnome3 and I have tried to make shortcuts for gnome-terminal, specially to set a title for a tab in terminal.

So how can I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The functionality is still there, I have it set to `ctrl+e` myself and use it daily. Visit `Edit/Keyboard Shortcuts...`, scroll down to the Terminal tree and set the `Set Title` keyboard shortcut.

It did take me a short time to find the Edit menu in 13.10. It appears that unless you enable `Show Menubar` the appmenu is hidden even if you hover over it with your mouse. You can re-enable the menu by right clicking on your terminal and selecting `Show Menubar`. Then when you hover over the unity panel, the menu will appear.

Comment: That's true, it is still there... I should be really tired not to find it. Actually, I found in `Edit/Preferences`, then tab Shortcuts.

Comment: Is this still possible in v 3.16.2? I can find the shortcut settings, but nothing like "Set title". However, I use the German version, so perhaps its poorly translated.

Comment: Thanks Edit/Keyboard shortcuts works well, I used `Ctrl` + `T` for the shortcut, "T" for title.

Answer (score 2):

1. When the terminal window is active, select *edit/keyboard
   shortcuts*.
2. In the window that opens, from the 'terminal' group,
       click on 'set title' and enter your desired key combination. I chose
       <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>  as per the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

Install xttitle (`sudo apt-get install xttitle`) (note the two 't's), read `man xttitle`, and use it.

```
xttitle "This is my title"
```